# Highlighting operation in pandas DataFrame by specific way defined

Tags: pandas, dataframe, colors, termcolor

I have my script to highlight 2 max values for columns in my `DataFrame` as:

```
from termcolor import colored
import pandas as pd

data = {'Col1': [190, 88, 120, 170, 110, 150], 'Col2': [11, -6, 3, 16, -21, 8], 'Col3': [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45],'Col4': [-33, -8, 93, -18, 3, 23], 'Col5': [544, 19, 78, 270, 210, 369]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def hightlight(series, excluded, spcl_col, spcl_val):
    if series.name == spcl_col:
        spcl_val = str(spcl_val)
        return series.astype(str).apply(lambda x: colored(x, None, 'on_green') if x == spcl_val else colored(x, 'white'))

    if series.name in excluded:
        return series.astype(str).apply(lambda x: colored(x, 'white'))
    colors = pd.Series([(None,'on_blue'), (None,'on_magenta')] + [('white',)]*(len(series)-2), index=series.sort_values(ascending=False).index).reindex(series.index)

    return [colored(str(x), *c) for x,c in zip(series, colors)]

col_to_exclude = ['Col3']
print(df.apply(hightlight, excluded=col_to_exclude, spcl_col='Col3', spcl_val=30)
.rename(columns=lambda x: colored(x, 'white', None)).to_string(index=False))
```

Now I want to add something in my above script so that all negative values are in red text and all positive values in green text for specific columns(let's say Col2 & Col4 here which can be changed) without using df.style method and text colour should not be changed for highlighted values already by above script.

Haw can I do it ??

Comment: How do you want to use the same function if in the first case, you exclude 'Col3' and the second case, you exclude 'Col2' and 'Col4'?

Comment: Yes true. Is there any way to combine highlighting top 2 values for costom columns and negative values in red and positive values in green for costom columns ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to reorganize your code to use subfunctions to format each series type. Having a modular code will make it easier to add extra functions. I also reworked a bit the logic to highlight the top two values:

```
from termcolor import colored
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1': [190, 88, 120, 170, 110, 150], 'Col2': [11, -6, 3, 16, -21, 8], 'Col3': [20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45],'Col4': [-33, -8, 93, -18, 3, 23], 'Col5': [544, 19, 78, 270, 210, 369]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def hightlight(series, excluded, spcl_col, spcl_val, extra_col=[]):

    def excl_formatter(series):
        return [colored(str(x), 'white') for x in series]
    
    def norm_formatter(series, extra=False):
        tmp = series.sort_values()
        if extra:
            tmp.iloc[:-2] = tmp.iloc[:-2].map(lambda x: colored(x,
                                              *[('white',),
                                                ('green',),
                                                ('red',),
                                               ][np.sign(x)])
                                             )
        else:
            tmp.iloc[:-2] = tmp.iloc[:-2].map(lambda x: colored(str(x), 'white'))
        tmp.iloc[-2] = colored(tmp.iloc[-2], None, 'on_magenta')
        tmp.iloc[-1] = colored(tmp.iloc[-1], None, 'on_blue')
        return tmp
        
    def spcl_formatter(series):
        return [colored(x, None, 'on_green') if x == spcl_val
                else colored(x, 'white')
                for x in series]
    
    if series.name == spcl_col:
        return spcl_formatter(series)
    if series.name in excluded:
        return excl_formatter(series)
    return norm_formatter(series, extra=series.name in extra_col)
                                                        
col_to_exclude = ['Col5']
print()
print(df.apply(hightlight, excluded=col_to_exclude, spcl_col='Col3',
               spcl_val=30, extra_col=['Col2', 'Col4'])
        .rename(columns=lambda x: colored(x, 'white', None)).to_string(index=False)
     )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: wow!!!! Thank you. Community is downvoting my question but you did it for me. Can you change the script for +values in green text not green background and same for -values in red text not on red background plz.

Comment: Sure, just change the tuples in `*[('white',), ('green',), ('red',)]`. If you use a tuple of 2 values (`(None, 'on_green')`) this assigns the background color, a tuple of a single value (`('green',)`) will assign the font color.

Comment: Sir I have two different DataFrames and I have added few columns from 2nd DataFrame to the first using fillna() function as both DataFrames have unequal rows. Now if I'm applying this highlighting function to the combined DataFrame, it's not working. Can you help me plz.